# PrimeFaces any input change event

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to get event when any input in `panelGroup` has been changed?

I don't want to add change listener to each single input. They're dynamically rendered. I thought about `jQuery`, but I want to handle the possibility of newly entered components.

Comment: `change` bubbles, so you can add the `change` listener to a closest common ancestor element.

Comment: @Teemu You can answer my question so I could mark it as aswered :)